# xpath query to search string in a webpage

Tags: c#, xpath, xquery, html-agility-pack, xpathquery

I am using html agility for below task.

I am wondering what can be **xpath query** to get all the nodes containing a string search term. It should search both attributes and innertext of elements.

```
<HTML>
 <BODY >
  <H1>Mr T for president</H1>
   <div class="test">We believe the new president should be</div>
   <div id="test">the awsome Mr T</div>
   <div>
    <H2>Mr T replies:</H2>
     <p>test paragraph</p>
     <p class="test">for Mr T</p>
   </div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

say I want to get all html elements have test either in their attributes or innertext?

Comment: Um... HTML isn't XML. XPath is a tool for XML.

Comment: I want to modify tag data or attribute to something else containing test as search string.

Comment: So use an Html parser. HtmlAgilityPack is great. Grab it with nuget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all element nodes that contain a given token in an attribute value or text node, you can use this:

```
//*[text()[contains(., 'token')] or @*[contains(., 'token')]]
```

Be aware that this will fail when the text is interrupted by other markup, for example in `<p>foo<em>bar</em></p>`.

Comment: that worked after small alteration as you missed a ] there. I have another question - I have this term as my search term !@#$%^&(.txt but for this result comes as null? Why?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo, fixed that. I don't see any direct issue with your search token, but the ampersand could be a problem. Is it correctly escaped in your HTML input?

Comment: Yes it is, but I get null result for this search token. It is passed as '!@#$%^&(.txt', where this search token is file name.

Comment: Try to replace `&` by its entity `&amp;`, and make sure it is also correctly encoded in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPath to match keyword 'test' against element's inner text or attribute value :

```
//*[contains(text(), 'test') or @*[contains(., 'test')]]
```

Comment: This will fail for all elements with multiple text nodes, as `contains($string, $needle)` does only accept single strings as input.